# Matlab projective transformation to Python

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, transformation, homography

I would like to convert a code from Matlab to Python, to do compute image transformation using projective transformation. My biggest problem is that I can't get the same transformation using openCV that I get from Matlab.

The matlab code is:

```
points = detectSIFTFeatures(img);
        [features, points] = extractFeatures(img,points);
        indexPairs = matchFeatures(features,featuresPrev,'Unique',true);
        matchedPoints = points(indexPairs(:,1),:);
        matchedPointsPrev = pointsPrev(indexPairs(:,2),:);
        T(k) = estimateGeometricTransform( ...
            matchedPoints,matchedPointsPrev,'projective','Confidence',...
            99.9,'MaxNumTrials',2000);
```

And my Python code is:

```
kp, des = sift.detectAndCompute(img, None)
# match & save the corresponding points & features of each pair of frame 
matches = flann.knnMatch(prev_des, des, k=2)
good = []
for m, n in matches:
     if m.distance < 0.9*n.distance:
         good.append(m)

if len(good) > MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
     src_pts = np.float32([prev_kp[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
     dst_pts = np.float32([kp[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

T[k], _ = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 1.5, confidence=0.999, maxIters=2000)
```

For the first iteration I get from Matlab :

```
[1.0018    0.0003    0.0000
 0.0011    1.0011    0.0000
-1.1988   -0.0775    1.0000]
```

And the one from Python:

```
[0.9982    0.00025    0.0000
 0.0015    0.99864    0.0000
-1.1973   -0.07605    1.0000]
```

So you can think that it is quite the same but in the end my result is very different, as I have to inverse some matrices.
So do you know any way to get the same transformation from Matlab to Python ?

Comment: Given the two are different languages, results will be inherently different. Your results differ by about one per cent though, is that really that big a problem? Will this still be the case after running through all iterations, rather than just the first?

Comment: 1) you do not need to invert any matrix, transformation matrices only need to be transposed 2)those transforms are almost the same, so if the application of them results in wildly different results, is the application of them that is wrong, not the matrices/

Comment: There are two main differenced between MATLAB and Python (OpenCV) transformation convention: **1.** MATLAB transformation matrix is multiplied from the right side of the coordinate vector, and OpenCV is multiplied from the left side. **2.** MATLAB top-left coordinate applies (1, 1) and OpenCV top-left coordinate applies (0, 0). If you want, I can answer how to convert MATLAB transformation matrix to OpenCV transformation matrix. When using two different algorithms/implementations "end to end" there may be other differences. For testing, build two images with known transformation.

Comment: Well I think that I understand what you said. But I tried with other two images and the result is then very different so I don't know what to do.

Comment: What I meant is that you take a sample image, define a simple transformation matrix, warp the [same] image using the transformation matrix (crop the relevant part for removing the margins from both images). Execute image matching, and make sure the transformation is close to the sample transformation.